# Output-ing functions into a text box, tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter, sqlite

Please can you help me out? I am trying to create buttons that follow a function then output in a text box, this is my code so far:

```
root = Tk()
menu = Menu(root)
root.config(menu=menu)
filemenu = Menu(menu)
root.filemenu = filedialog.askopenfilename()
menu.add_cascade(label="New Measures", menu=newMeasures)
filemenu.add_command(label="See all measures", command=getMeasures)
filemenu.add_command(label="See the total rain", command=totalRain)
filemenu.add_command(label="See the total electricity", command=totalElectricity)
filemenu.add_command(label="See the measures for a date", command=find_date)
#filemenu.add_command(label="Change the data for a date", command=edit_date)
filemenu.add_separator()
filemenu.add_command(label="Exit", command=root.destroy)
```

But it is not doing anything - it just shows an empty tk() box

Comment: Your code does not create any text boxes and raises `NameError`.

Comment: 1. You are not using a text-box in this code. 2. `root.filemenu` is a terrible name for a variable and honestly I didn't even think `root.filemenu` would work. 3. you have all these labels and each one has different commands but you do not show what these functions are doing so there is no way to know what is wrong with your code. 4. You need to also include the imports you are using.

Answer (score 0):

When you add the first dropdown button to the menu you are trying to put it in the menu "newMeasures", which does not exist.

```
menu.add_cascade(label="New Measures", menu=newMeasures)
```

The menu you created is called "filemenu".

```
menu.add_cascade(label="New Measures", menu=filemenu)
```